# Use existing source code in another project/namespace

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, repository

I have two library projects within a single solution (in addition to other projects) which necessarily need to share certain classes but must remain separate for automatic-update reasons.

For the classes that are shared, I would ideally like to use the same `class.cs` file in both libraries so that I don't have to consistently check that changes to the class are propagated through both libraries.

**However** the namespaces of the two libraries are different, and so the class-containing file in each library requires a different `namespace classlib {}` declaration.

I am using a git repo, if there is a technique to do this through branch/merge operations.
Presently using VS2013.

How can I achieve this?

---

Example:

`library1.dll`

```
namespace library1
{
    public class SharedClass
    {
        /// code must match SharedClass in libary2
    }
}
```

`library2.dll`

```
namespace libary2
{
    public class SharedClass
    {
        /// code must match SharedClass in library1
    }
}
```

Comment: Its not clear what you are asking

Comment: Why the same class belongs to two different namespaces?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan Because I need the same class to be present in two different libraries, within the same solution. I need to be able to update the library.dll files separately.

Comment: Why not create a new DLL that both DLL's can reference? Sounds like a design issue to me. I have never met a case where I really needed to duplicate code

Comment: Do you think that code of one assembly can't belongs to two different namespaces?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan I do think that! Can you show me how?

Comment: file class1.cs `namespace Ns1{public class Class1{}}` file class2.cs `namespace Ns2{public class Class2{}}` Then `csc /target:library class1.cs class2.cs`

Comment: @HamletHakobyan doesn't that just create a single `library.dll` file with two classes in two namespaces?  What I need are two separate, independent, libary DLLs, which share common source code.

Comment: @Frode I absolutely do not want to duplicate code.  Looking for a way to share the same source code that needs to exist in two namespaces.

Comment: As you have written in your post your problem is `However the namespaces of the two libraries are different, and so the class-containing file in each library requires a different namespace classlib {} declaration.` So, I want to mention that there can't be such a problem at all.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan thanks for your advice, I don't think I understand. How can I include the same class.cs file in two different libraries? Each library has it's own namespace, and the class in class.cs must be declared within just 1 namespace?

Comment: I try to ensure you that each library can contain more than one namespaces.

Comment: I understand that the library can contain more than one namespace.  But the namespace declaration is part of the class name. How can the same class exist in two namespaces?

Comment: This class would have the same namespace in both libraries. (e.g. `namespace Common`.)

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes aha! There's the click. Then I can include the source code as a linked file from one project into the other.

Comment: Would you please make an answer to that end, I think this is actually the best answer to this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Declare the SharedClass in a common namespace, instead of two different namespaces. You could link the file into the projects instead of including it physically.

From [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj714082%28v=vs.105%29.aspx):

> You link to a file from your project in Visual Studio. In Solution Explorer, right-click your project, and then select Add Existing item Or, you can type Shift+Alt+A. In the Add Existing Item dialog box, select the file you want to add, and in the Add drop-down list, click Add As Link.

```
namespace Khargoosh.MathLib.Common   { public class SharedClass { ... }  }
namespace Khargoosh.MathLib.Library1 { ... }
namespace Khargoosh.MathLib.Library2 { ... }
```

or

```
namespace Khargoosh.MathLib          { public class SharedClass { ... }  }
namespace Khargoosh.MathLib.Library1 { ... }
namespace Khargoosh.MathLib.Library2 { ... }
```

---

A completely other way of handling that would be to use the [T4 template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx) with some logic to create the file dynamically. Content of the *.tt template files (not *.cs files!):

```
namespace library1
{
<#@ include file="MyCommonClass.cs"#>
}
```

And in the other library

```
namespace library2
{
<#@ include file="MyCommonClass.cs"#>
}
```

The class file itself would not declare a namespace.

Comment: Yeah - that's exactly the sort of thing I was looking for.

Comment: I keep on getting below error while using your second solution  
`preprocessor directives must appear as the first non-whitespace character on a line`

Comment: For the [T4 template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/code-generation-and-t4-text-templates?view=vs-2015) solution, you would not create a *,cs file, but a *.tt file. This *.tt file (the template) then generates a *.cs file automatically. The Visual Studio extension *T4 Toolbox for Visual Studio* from Oleg Sych, is useful when working with T4 templates.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the info you've provided, if your shared classes are truly "common" you should create a 3rd library that both of your main libs can reference. for example:

MainLib1
   (**reference commonLib**)

MainLib2
   (**reference commonLib**)

**commonLib**
   (includes class.cs and other common code)

Comment: The classes are truly common, but the files can't be dependent on each other or on a third library.  The projects that uses library A must be able to remove/update Library B, and vice versa.

Comment: Won't both MainLib1.dll and MainLib2.dll require commonLib.dll to be present? If so, I won't be able to update commonLib.dll, as the classes that exist in commonLib.dll are required during the update of commonLib.dll.

Comment: a "commonLib" library would allow library A to remove/update library B.

Comment: to answer your other question, what is it exactly that you are trying to do? you want commonLib to be able to update itself?

Comment: Well yes, if I use that approach, I would want commonLib to be able to update itself.  But the application that performs the updating, needs the classes in commonLib to be available during the update.

Comment: @khargoosh: It is more common to share assemblies than source files. If `commonLib` changes but its interface is preserved and you are not signing the assemblies, you can update it without having to update the two other libs.

Comment: Thanks Olivier.  I understand that this is more common. However I need to deploy this product knowing that there may be a requirement that the interface is changed or added to.

Comment: So are you wanting the product to "self update" if there are changes? is this a standalone application or running service?

Comment: Self update, yes. The product is made up of two services and a winforms application.  Libary1 is used by one service, and Library2 is used by the other service and the application.

Comment: Thank you for the up votes, based on what khargoosh was actually trying to accomplish, I think the correct answer is actually from Olivier.

Answer (score 3):

> I need to be able to update the `library.dll` files separately

Then you should use submodules for this task.

Submodule are different git repositories under the same root.
This way you can manage 2 different project at folder level inside the root repository

[image]

Comment: Thanks @codeWizard. This sounds like a good approach. I'll do more research on this.